# Javadoc Inserting UML Diagrams

Tags: java, javadoc, class-diagram

Is there a way to embed images into my JavaDoc?  Basically i want to include some UML diagrams explaining the hierarchy of my classes in some of the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 I wish I would have asked this myself!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out [this section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#images) of the Javadoc documentation, which explains how to embed images in your Javadoc.

Also, here is an [article](https://dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u) describing how to reverse engineer UML diagrams and embed them in your Javadoc using [UMLGraph](https://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/).

Comment: UML Graph url is broken, changed owner

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

[The documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#images) explains how to embed arbitrary images to javadoc documentation.

If you want to generate UML class diagrams from your Java source, have a look at the [UMLGraph doclet](http://www.umlgraph.org/).

Comment: Also this article on using UML Graph http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://gochev.blogspot.cz/2011/03/generate-javadoc-with-uml-diagrams.html) shows how to use UMLGraph with Maven Javadoc plugin.

In short:

1. Install GraphViz.

   Ubuntu: `apt-get install graphviz4`.
   Windows: [download](http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php).
2. Update pom.xml.

   ```
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.7</version>
           <configuration>
               <aggregate>true</aggregate>
               <show>private</show>
               <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
               <docletArtifact>
                   <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
                   <artifactId>doclet</artifactId>
                   <version>5.1</version>
               </docletArtifact>
               <additionalparam>
                   -inferrel -attributes -types -visibility -inferdep -quiet -hide java.* -collpackages java.util.* -qualify -postfixpackage
                   -nodefontsize 9
                   -nodefontpackagesize 7
               </additionalparam>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. Run `mvn javadoc:javadoc`.

Comment: Clearly the easiest approach! Should add a profile for building these so you don't break other ppl's builds that don't have GraphViz in the path.

Answer (score 3):

[ApiViz](http://code.google.com/p/apiviz/) is a nice doclet too.

Comment: It seems long abandoned by now.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Answer:

```
/**
 * This class does some stuff (see diagram).
 * <img src="relative/path/to/image.png" />
 * 
 */
 public class SomeClass{
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[yDoc](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_ydoc.html) is an option

Comment: USD 269.00 for a single user license.

Comment: Is there OpenSource/free alternative for C#?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#images) explains how it can be done by placing your images in a folder accessible to the javadoc tool.