# Are there any software to generate UML Diagrams from analyzing code?

Tags: uml, tool-uml

I have a complex application with lots of class files. I'm using Doxygen to generate some documentation, but would love a tool that can statically analyze my code and generate some UML diagrams. Not sure if a product like this exists, but would love to hear the community input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools doing exactly this on various levels of quality. I would like to mention, that generating UML diagrams for documentation purposes might not be a great idea, especially in large projects. The problem is, that in complex code bases, there are many relationships between classes a lot of code is called etc. basically any diagram type you choose might in a particular project look bloated. Confusing diagram might be worse than well structured textual documentation. Basically what I am trying to say is, that main idea of modeling is to abstract from unimportant details and deciding automatically what is unimportant is not easy and often project dependent, therefore it is most of the times more useful to create far less diagrams manually, which will conatin much more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 kind of has this for C# and VB projects, and Visio 2003 back in the day could do them for .NET and C++ projects... Other tools, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about class diagrams, [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com) can do this for several languages, including Visual Basic, C#, Java and Python.

I also know that it has the ability to generate sequence diagrams by running .NET code in the debugger, but I don't know if that feature is available for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

[UMLGraph or apiviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713262/umlgraph-vs-apiviz-for-maven-javadoc-generation) may help if you're working in a java environment.

hth.