# UmlGraph not automatic integrated in JavaDoc

Tags: maven, javadoc, java

I'm using maven and the maven-javadoc-plugin with the umlgraph-doclet to create javadoc for my project. The part from my pom:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <configuration>
        <reportPlugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
              <show>public</show>
              <quiet>true</quiet>

              <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
              <docletArtifact>
                <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
                <artifactId>doclet</artifactId>
                <version>5.1</version>
              </docletArtifact>

              <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
              <additionalparam>
                -inferrel -inferdep -quiet -hide java.* -hide org.eclipse.* -collpackages java.util.* -postfixpackage
                -nodefontsize 9 -nodefontpackagesize 7 -attributes -types -visibility -operations -constructors
                -enumerations -enumconstants -views
              </additionalparam>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
              <reportSet>
                <reports>
                  <report>aggregate</report>
                </reports>
              </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
          </plugin>
        </reportPlugins>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The images are generated and look fine, when building the javadoc with jdk1.6 they get automatically integrated into all javadoc pages. But when building with jdk1.7, the images still get created but are not inside the javadoc pages. Even when using the v5.4 from the official website, the javadoc is imageless. And the debug output of maven also don't give any clue. On top of that, there is no way of contacting one of the UmlGraph devs by mail.

Can anyone give me some advice here, or have some ideas how to fix that?

Comment: My guess would be that the HTML pages produced by the standard doclet changed their structure between Java 6 and Java 7, so the UMLGraph doclet fails to plug in the generated images. No idea how to solve this (I never used this doclet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the possibilities, and the situation is following:.

- relevant bug in the UmlGraph has been already fixed: https://github.com/dspinellis/UMLGraph/pull/8
- problem is however that no stable version of UmlGraph has been released yet that would include the fix

However good news is that there exists snapshot repository containing the fix: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/umlgraph/umlgraph/5.5.8-SNAPSHOT/

Therefor you need to get the jar file to your local repository (depending on your infrastructure setup):

- either by adding reffered repository to your environment
- or by importing to your local repo (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

afterwards update:

```
<doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
<docletArtifact>
            <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>doclet</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
</docletArtifact>
```

to the following (naming convention has been changed):

```
<doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
<docletArtifact>
    <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>umlgraph</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
</docletArtifact>
```

Answer (score 11):

Update: version 5.6.6 is now on maven central. I built with JDK 7 and diagrams look ok.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <show>private</show>
        <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
        <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>umlgraph</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.6</version>
        </docletArtifact>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

UmlGraphDoc version 5.4, altering javadocs
Warning, could not find a line that matches the pattern '/H2'

The HTML is simply different.

Java7 JavaDocs
START OF CLASS DATA
h2 title="blah blah

Java6 JavaDocs
START OF CLASS DATA
H2

You can decompile and modify UmlGraphDoc.java

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My guess is that it's this bug:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/APIVIZ-10

Comment: isn't this apiviz rather than umlgraph related issue? I guess these 2 projects are separate. more details on difference seem to be present in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713262/umlgraph-vs-apiviz-for-maven-javadoc-generation